# Lane identification via loop

Tags: r

How to identify the entry, parent & child point for multiple items

Input:

```
    Item    LC      ToLC
1   0S1576  MW92    OY01
2   0S1576  OY01    RM11
3   0S1576  OY01    RS11
4   0S1576  RM11    WK14
5   0S1576  RM11    WK15
```

Input dataframe dput:

`structure(list(Item = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0S1576", class = "factor"), LC = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("MW92", "OY01", "RM11"), class = "factor"), ToLC = structure(1:5, .Label = c("OY01","RM11", "RS11", "WK14", "WK15"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))`

Lane is like this for one item 0S1576

```
0S1576   MW92->OY01->RM11->WK14->WK15
0S1576   MW92->OY01->RS11
```

For each item 
Entry will be MW92 
Parent will be OY01,RM11,WK14 
Child will be WK15,RS11

Output:

```
Item   Entry    Parent1   Parent2   Parent3   Child1   Child2
0S1576  MW92    OY01       RM11      WK14      WK15     RS11
```

Can someone help me how to identify the output

Comment: Maybe look into igraph? e.g.: `library(igraph); g <- graph_from_data_frame(df1); vertex(g)`